# secure alternative to dynamic port forwarding in mult-user environment

Tags: proxy, authentication, https, ssh-tunnel

My users work on [externalserver] in a foreign network. I want to enable them to access a https - service inside my firewalled network. I have a jumphost in the DMZ with passwordless ssh access enabled.

Currently I let them create a SSH SOCKS5 forwarding proxy:

```
user@externalserver> ssh -Nf -D 9876 user@jumphost
```

and let them point the socksified application to localhost:9876.

The problem is that once this tunnel is established, all users on [externalserver] can access my internal https-service through it. Apparently ssh does not provide authentication for the SOCKS proxy.

How can I achieve this functionality but prevent non-authorized users on [externalserver] to access my network? Preferable would be a solution that works passwordless. I have no admin-rights on [externalserver].